# D3, transition groups (<g>)

Tags: d3.js, svg, transition

In D3 is it possible to transition groups?

With square or circles it works this way:

```
mySquare
  .transition()
  .attr("x",320);
```

but if mySquare is for example a reference to a group ("< g >") it doesn't work, maybe because D3 looks for an x property of the group I was not able to retrieve.

Can you help me? I couldn't find any docs about this topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the `x` attribute is not valid for an svg `g` element, transitioning it will not work as intended.  You can, however, transition the `transform` attribute to transition the position of a group of elements, or transition styles that cascade to it's children.

i.e.:

```
myGroup.transition()
    .attr("transform", "translate(320, 0)")
    .style("fill", "red");
```

Comment: Very clear and interesting, thank you very much. It's strange SVG doesn't have a valid an x property: I thought groups were like ActionScript MovieClips or Sprites.